# Defining Tegmark's level IV multiverse

Tags: definition, multiverse

I am bit bothered by the "definition" of Tegmark's level IV [multiverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiverse). I have read that it is a "collection of all mathematical models" (whatever that means). I have also read that in this multiverse "all possible mathematical structures have a physical existence."

Can anyone makes some sense out of this, or precisely define it ?

Are the following examples mathematical structures in this context?

- differential equations;
- the set $\{ a, b, c \}$;
- a projective space    over the complex numbers;
- some specified axiom.

How are all these (in general very different) structures/models/etc. mathematically collected ?

*Bonus question*: how do we see/represent our own observable universe in Tegmark level IV ?

Answer (score 3):

> Are the following examples mathematical structures in this context ?

Yes, all of those are examples of mathematical structures. In Tegmark's Level IV multiverse, all of those (and, indeed, any other mathematical structure, including ones that are inconsistent or self-contradictory or have not been discovered yet) have a physical existence.

> How are all these (in general very different) structures/models/etc. mathematically collected ?

Not sure what you mean by "collected". In the Level IV multiverse they just *are*. We can explore the Level IV multiverse by thinking about these structures (every time you do simple arithmetic, you are exploring the Level IV multiverse) or by running computer programs which do the "exploring" for us.

> How do we see/represent our own observable universe in Tegmark level IV ?

The Level IV multiverse does not change how we see or perceive our observable universe in any way. It does provide some explanations of why the observable universe is the way it is. Why do mathematical laws describe the observable universe so well ? Because it is a small piece of the multiverse which is inherently mathematical in nature. Why is the observable universe the way it is ? Because it is only a very very small piece of the multiverse, and other "universe" pieces exist for any conceivable set of initial conditions and physical laws (although many of them cannot support life as we know it). Why does time seem to flow in one direction ? Time is an illusion - the Level IV multiverse is timeless and the whole of our universe's spacetime (as well as spacetime or its equivalent for other pieces of the multiverse) exists simultaneously. There are versions of "you" elsewhere in the multiverse that perceive time in very different ways.

By the way, if you think that saying "everything that you can imagine (as well as everything that you cannot imagine) exists somewhere in an unchanging timeless multiverse" is all a bit of a philosophical cop out, you are not alone.